# How can I show the appropriate submenu on each page?

Tags: angular

When I am on

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

[image: img - 1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYH9N.png)

Then, I click on `Administration`

A submenu is display

[image: img - 2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZK4T.png)

Now, I click on `Portfolio`

[image: img - 3][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6anaX.png)

The submenu has disappeared ???

[image: img - 4][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UjBs.png)

I would like my submenu to remain activated.

However, if I am already on the `Portfolio`

[image: Portfolio][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAgCG.png)

And that I click on `Account Opening`

[image: Account Opening][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXiVO.png)

The submenu is activated correctly!

I don't understand where is the problem?

I think that the problem is on `administration.routing.ts` ?

```js
    export const routes: Routes = [
     
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
    
        children: [
    
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'portfolio',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          
          {
            path: 'portfolio',
            component: PortfolioComponent,
          },
    
          {
            path: 'account-opening',
            component: AccountOpeningComponent,
          },
    
        ]
     
      },
    
    ];
```

In dashboard.component.ts, the path seems to be good

```js
    menus: any[] = [
    
        /* Administration */
        {
          class: 'bx bx-lock-alt',
          item: 'Administration',
          route: '/dashboard/adiministration',
          arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
          arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',
    
          submenus: [
            {
              class: 'bx bx-key',
              item: 'Account Opening',
              route: '/administration/account-opening',
            },
            {
              class: 'bx bx-wallet',
              item: 'Portfolio',
              route: '/administration/portfolio',
            },
           
          ],
        },
    
        /* Market */
        {
          class: 'bx bx-chart',
          item: 'Market',
          route: '/dashboard/market',
          arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
          arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',
    
          submenus: [
            {
              class: 'bx bx-coin-stack',
              item: 'Value',
              route: '/market/value',
            },
            {
              class: 'bx bx-line-chart',
              item: 'Indice',
              route: '/market/indice',
            },
           
          ],
        },
       
      ];
```

I can give you the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yt5rck?file=src/app/dashboard/administration/administration-routing.module.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at your configuration at "dashboard-rouding.module" then you see

```
{
  path: '',
  component: DashboardComponent,
},
 {
    path: 'administration', // totaly different instance of DashboardComponent will be rendered on this path because of the configuration provided.
    loadChildren: () => import('./administration/administration.module').then((m) => m.AdministrationModule),
  },
```

and because new Dashboard component is rendered - state of menues is not saved. to fix that I propose to put both child modules in children section

```
{
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'administration',
        loadChildren: () => import('./administration/administration.module').then((m) => m.AdministrationModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'market',
        loadChildren: () => import('./market/market.module').then((m) => m.MarketModule),
      },
    ]
  },
```

and remove duplicate the Dashboard component in those modules,because it is no longer needed there

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in fact I have to keep the `dashboard`,` administration` and `market` folder, I'm really stuck. I do not understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: keep the folders, but change just the routing configuration. make dashboard module configuration like in my answer and remove the root Dashboard component from administration and market configuration. the rest should stay the same